# PowerShell - How can I use regex in the middle of registry file path to perform remove-item operation?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, powershell-7.3

I've looked at many similar questions and tried lots of things, but I can't make it work.

```
$Regex = 'RegexPattern'
    
    
    Remove-Item -Path 'HKCU:System\somePath\' + $Regex + '\MorePath\*' -Recurse
    
    Remove-Item -Path "HKCU:System\somePath\$Regex\MorePath\*" -Recurse
    
    Remove-Item -Path "HKCU:System\somePath\$($Regex)\MorePath\*" -Recurse

    Remove-Item -Path "HKCU:System\somePath\'RegexPattern'\MorePath\*" -Recurse

    Remove-Item -Path 'HKCU:System\somePath\"RegexPattern"\MorePath\*' -Recurse
```

None of those work.

I have a regex, want to delete only children of a folder with remove-item but I don't know how to make it parse the regex instead of taking the pattern literally.

Comment: Is there a reason wildcard patterns wouldn't suffice here? If you're really set on using RegEx, since Reg.-Keys are read as items in PS Drives, you can apply most of the same logic as you would to your main file system drive. So, `Get-ChildItem` can query the keys just like a regular drive with the main difference being keys are containers and the properties may be distinct from one another. Just specify the registry provider you're after then apply some logic to it: `gci hklm:\... | ? { $_ -match $pattern }`

Comment: As an aside: Only `"HKCU:System\somePath\$Regex\MorePath\*"` would work  `"HKCU:System\somePath\$($Regex)\MorePath\*"` _syntactically_ as intended (proper string interpolation). `'HKCU:System\somePath\' + $Regex + '\MorePath\*'` would only work if you enclosed it in `(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-Path` parameter accepts [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), not [regexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions).

To apply regex matching, use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), filter the results with [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object), which allows you to perform regex matching with the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator, and apply [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) to the results; along the following lines:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path HKCU:\System\somePath\*\MorePath |
  Where-Object Name -match $RegexPattern | 
  Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- The above uses wildcard `*` to match the keys of *potential* interest, to be filtered via the regex later; adjust as needed.
- Since you're processing *registry keys*, `.Name` refers to the *full, registry-native key path*, such as `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\...`, given that the registry keys output  by `Get-ChildItem` are represented as [`[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey) instances.
- The `Where-Object` call uses [*simplified syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax), which in simple cases such as this enables a more concise syntax; it is the equivalent of the following: 
  `Where-Object { $_.Name -match $RegexPattern }`

Comment: Thank you, that worked just like I wanted, I think I saw this method somewhere but didn't use it because I saw `.Name` being used and didn't know it refers to the full registry native key path, but with your explanation now I know how it works.